# Изменить ветку по умолчанию git

Tags: git

Забыл создать ветку по умолчанию теперь у меня ветвление идёт от ветки, которую я не хочу использовать как ветку по умолчанию. Можно ли в новую ветку по умолчанию подтянуть имеющиеся ветки что они начинали ветвиться от неё. Пока есть только два коммита

Comment: Поправьте свой комментарий так, чтоб было показан вывод `git log --all --10` ? Укажите какие именно комиты вы хотите перенести в другую ветку и с каким ее названием?

Comment: просто переименуйте ветку `git branch -m желаемое_название`

Answer (score 1):

Если ваша ветка ещё не находится в общедоступном репозитории, то вы можете переписать историю, изменив точку ветвления.

Для этого нужно выполнить интерактивный `rebase`, и перенести на новую начальную точку только коммиты из вашей ветки (2 штуки). Вероятнее всего rebase захочет перенести и вашу текущую ветку, и ту от которой вы ответвились. Поэтому нужен интерактивный режим.